# How does react decide to rerender a component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-lifecycle-hooks

I know React has a life cycle method called `shouldComponentUpdate`, Which by default return true and that's how the component decides to update

But How does that life cycle method gets called, When a state or props change for that component. What actually happens when we receive new props or state? When We connect a component to redux state and mapStateToProps, Are we checking for a change in values inside the component? If not, When We are looking for a change in state or props?

when the props or state changes, how the life cycle methods are called?. Do we have a listener that calls these methods when the props or state changes?

Answer (score 18):

You should look at lifecycles of both, how they perform and in what order each method gets called. Looking at react lifecycle image bellow you can see the difference between `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` and others like `componentDidUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate` and so on...

*Also you should reason when to use each method*

To update state you call `this.setState()` which tells react that something has changed and it will re-render component tree. If you use `this.state.data = something` react won't trigger render(). Now to update props, you need to understand how render() actually works. This answer is summarized from existing anwser already:

> Every time render() is called react will create a new virtual DOM
>   where the root node is the component whose render function is called.
>   The render() function is called when either the state or the props of
>   a component or any of its children change. The render() function
>   destroys all of the old virtual DOM nodes starting from the root and
>   creates a brand new virtual DOM.
>
> In order to make sure the re-rendering of components is smooth and
>   efficient React uses the Diffing Algorithm to reduce the time it takes
>   to create a new tree to a time complexity of O(n), usually time
>   complexity for copying trees is > O(n^2). The way it accomplishes this
>   is by using the "key" attribute on each of the elements in the DOM.
>   React knows that instead of creating each element from scratch it can
>   check the "key" attribute on each node in the DOM. This is why you get
>   a warning if you don't set the "key" attribute of each element, React
>   uses the keys to vastly increase its rendering speed.

React Lifecycle

[image]

Redux Lifecycle

[image]

Comment: My question  is when the props or state changes, how the life cycle methods are called?. Do we have a listener that calls these methods when the props or state changes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a few doubts about the answer. You have explained how render works. But For to call render it should come through lifecycle methods right (like `componentWillUpdate`, `shouldComponentUpdate`). My question is how do these methods are invoked internally? When the props changes it will call `componentWillRecieveProps` right, But How is it getting called? How react knows to invoke these lifecycle methods?

Answer (score -1):

If you use `redux` library, may be, your component does not re-render after your props changes. Checkout [this issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/221) to resolve the props changes problem with `componentWillReceiveProps`